# Customizing ROLLUP row mySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to summarize the sales data and I want to sum its total in the last row, I'm using "GROUP BY" and "WITH ROLLUP" but the results are:

```
+--------+--------------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|   id   |        name        |    date    | amount |   total   |
+--------+--------------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| Z00015 | Mebel Harmonis     | 2019-05-09 |      2 |  10000000 |
| Z00016 | Mebel Harmonis     | 2019-05-09 |     10 |  45000000 |
| Z00017 | Mebel Tunggal Jaya | 2019-05-10 |      3 |  12000000 |
| (null) | Mebel Tunggal Jaya | 2019-05-10 |     29 | 131000000 |
+--------+--------------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

the last row that i want:

```
+--------+--------+--------+----+-----------+   
| (null) | (null) | (null) | 29 | 131000000 |
+--------+--------+--------+----+-----------+
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    order2.id_order AS id,
    customer.name_customer AS name,
    DATE( order2.date_order ) AS date ,
    Count( order_detail.id_detail ) AS amount,
    SUM( harga ) AS total 
FROM
    order_detail
    INNER JOIN order2 ON order2.id_order = order_detail.id_order
    INNER JOIN customer ON order2.id_customer = customer.id_customer
    INNER JOIN produk ON produk.id_produk = order_detail.id_produk
    INNER JOIN sofa ON sofa.id_sofa = produk.id_sofa 
WHERE
    date( date_order ) >= '2019-05-01' 
    AND date( date_order ) <= '2019-05-31' 
GROUP BY
    order2.id_order WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Just change your `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY id, name, \`date\` WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling display issues such as this in application code

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all the columns that can be combined together for the grand total in your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY id, name, date WITH ROLLUP
```

However, this will create intermediate subtotals for each `id` and `id, name`. You can filter them out with:

```
HAVING id IS NOT NULL OR (id IS NULL AND name IS NULL AND date IS NULL)
```